# Rails correct association with non-standard foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two tables:

```
Languages: id, name, abbreviation
Post: id, title, language
```

Post.language is connected to Language.abbreviation.

How do I set up the Models so I can correctly call:

```
@post.language.name
```

and receive the name of the language it's connected to?

What I was starting with was:

```
Post> 
  belongs_to :language

Language>
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => "abbreviation"
```

But that doesn't seem to be connecting properly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the language_id in the Post model, instead of the abbreviation. You can connect the abbreviations in forms to show the abbreviation, but store the language_id in the database.

Comment: Normally I'd do that @Solomon, but I have this data importing from a third source so I'm trying to work around doing a lookup for each record on import as 99% of the time only the abbreviation is used. Right now the Posts import with a language tag with the standard 2 character abbreviation.

Comment: How many languages are there in total? Might it just be easier to make the language's into a Hash? Do they need ActiveRecord functionality?

Comment: Probably about 150+, so not sure that's a practical way to do it. I will probably end up reworking my import to do a lookup by id and go from there. Thanks for the help @Solomon.

Comment: You could definitely still do 150+ in a Hash, or put them in a yml file and use something like this: https://github.com/quirkey/static_model/